# What does the delayed() function do (when used with joblib in Python)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I've read through the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html), but I don't understand what is meant by:
 `The delayed function is a simple trick to be able to create a tuple (function, args, kwargs) with a function-call syntax.`

I'm using it to iterate over the list I want to operate on (allImages) as follows:

```
def joblib_loop():
    Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(getHog)(i) for i in allImages)
```

This returns my HOG features, like I want (and with the speed gain using all my 8 cores), but I'm just not sure what it is actually doing.

My Python knowledge is alright at best, and it's very possible that I'm missing something basic. Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated

Comment: I did come across [THIS DOC](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/joblib/latest/joblib.pdf) but I am also trying to figure out what `delayed` does

Comment: I did three programs for image processing 1. without using `joblib`, 2. using `joblib` and `delayed` but **without** `Parallel` and finally 3. using all the three. The time taken to process the images decreased by the third for each case. So using `delayed` without `Parallel` speeds things up but I don't know how

Comment: do share if you come across something

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Perhaps things become clearer if we look at what would happen if instead we simply wrote

```
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(getHog(i) for i in allImages)
```

which, in this context, could be expressed more naturally as:

1. Create a `Parallel` instance with `n_jobs=8`
2. create a generator for the list `[getHog(i) for i in allImages]`
3. pass that generator to the `Parallel` instance

What's the problem? By the time the list gets passed to the `Parallel` object, all `getHog(i)` calls have already returned - so there's nothing left to execute in Parallel! All the work was already done in the main thread, sequentially.

What we *actually* want is to tell Python what functions we want to call with what arguments, *without actually calling them* - in other words, we want to *delay* the execution.

This is what `delayed` conveniently allows us to do, with clear syntax. If we want to tell Python that we'd like to call `foo(2, g=3)` sometime later, we can simply write `delayed(foo)(2, g=3)`. Returned is the tuple `(foo, [2], {g: 3})`, containing:

- a reference to the **function** we want to call, e.g.`foo`
- all **arguments** (short "args") without a keyword, e.g.t `2`
- all **keyword arguments** (short "kwargs"), e.g. `g=3`

So, by writing `Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(getHog)(i) for i in allImages)`, instead of the above sequence, now the following happens:

1. A `Parallel` instance with `n_jobs=8` gets created
2. The list

   ```
    [delayed(getHog)(i) for i in allImages]
   ```

   gets created, evaluating to

   ```
    [(getHog, [img1], {}), (getHog, [img2], {}), ... ]
   ```
3. That list is passed to the `Parallel` instance
4. The `Parallel` instance creates 8 threads and distributes the tuples from the list to them
5. Finally, each of those threads starts executing the tuples, i.e., they call the first element with the second and the third elements unpacked as arguments `tup[0](*tup[1], **tup[2])`, turning the tuple back into the call we actually intended to do,  `getHog(img2)`.

Comment: `Pararell` is a typo, I guess. I duckduckgoed it.

Comment: @Nearoo - People like you should become professors/teachers and must be paid like CEOs. Not all teachers are good at teaching, but you are. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

we need a loop to test a list of different model configurations. This is the main function that drives the grid search process and will call the score_model() function for each model configuration. We can dramatically speed up the grid search process by evaluating model configurations in parallel. One way to do that is to use the Joblib library . We can define a Parallel object with the number of cores to use and set it to the number of scores detected in your hardware.

## define executor

`executor = Parallel(n_jobs=cpu_count(), backend= 'multiprocessing' )`

then create a list of tasks to execute in parallel, which will be one call to the score model() function for each model configuration we have.

suppose `def score_model(data, n_test, cfg):
                   ........................`

## define list of tasks

`tasks = (delayed(score_model)(data, n_test, cfg) for cfg in cfg_list)`

we can use the Parallel object to execute the list of tasks in parallel.

`scores = executor(tasks)`

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to be able to do is pile up a set of function calls and their arguments in such a way that you can pass them out efficiently to a scheduler/executor.  Delayed is a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) that takes in a function and its args and wraps them into an object that can be put in a list and popped out as needed.  Dask has the same thing which it uses in part to feed into its graph scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The post by LakshayAAAgrawal is a good explanation of how it works. I would like to add some details on how a convenient implementation may look like:

```py
import joblib

@joblib.delayed
def getHog(image):
    """Some time-consuming function on an image"""
    ...

# Running this in parallel
with joblib.Parallel(backend="loky", n_jobs=8) as parallel:
    result = parallel(getHog(img) for img in allImages)
```

Please note that the call to `parallel(getHog(...)...)` doesn't require the `delayed()` call, because the latter has already been added as a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) to the function definition.

Answer (score -5):

From reference https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing
The Parallel object creates a multiprocessing pool that forks the Python interpreter in multiple processes to execute each of the items of the list. The delayed function is a simple trick to be able to create a tuple (function, args, kwargs) with a function-call syntax.

Another thing I would like to suggest is instead of explicitly defining num of cores we can generalize like this:

```
import multiprocessing
num_core=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the OP's question of how delayed works. You've restated the statement about the delayed function verbatim.