# One minimal example of joblib runs on all 4 cores another only on one. Fix?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I am trying to use some parallel computations in my implementation of machine learning algorithms, using `joblib`, especially the technique used on [this page](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html).
The following examples are for me to understand parallelism, I have the same problem as the second example in my ML algorithms.

This example runs on all 4 cores as expected:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

N_PARAM = 10000
N_TEST_FUN = 10000000

def testfunc(data):
    for _ in range(N_TEST_FUN):
        for i in data:
                i*i

def run(niter=10):
    data = [list(range(N_PARAM)) for _ in range(niter)]
    pool = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, pre_dispatch='all')
    results = pool(delayed(testfunc)(dd) for dd in data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

While this example only runs on 1:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

N_PARAM = 10000
N_TEST_FUN = 10000000

def testfunc():
    for _ in range(N_TEST_FUN):
        for i in range(N_PARAM):
            i**2

def run(niter=10):
    pool = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, pre_dispatch="all")
    pool(testfunc() for _ in range(niter))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

which I do not understand at all. Why is that ?

I am Ubuntu 18.10, I use joblib 0.13.2 and python 3.6.8 from an Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find an answer there:
[what-does-the-delayed-function-do-when-used-with-joblib-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220458/what-does-the-delayed-function-do-when-used-with-joblib-in-python)
The accepted answer is well explained.

From my understanding, your second example the `pool(testfunc() for _ in range(niter))` returns the result before the function can be pass to the multiprocess.