# Parallel loop in python with joblib throws weird error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

i am trying to run a very simple parallel loop in python

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

my_array = np.zeros((2,3))

def foo(array,x):
  for i in [0,1,2]:
     array[x][i]=25
     print(array, id(array), 'arrays in workers')

def main(array):
  print(id(array), 'Original array')
  inputs = [0,1]
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parallel(n_jobs=8, verbose = 0)((foo)(array,i) for i in inputs)
#     print(my_array, id(array), 'Original array')

main(my_array)
```

which does alter the array in the end but i get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 252, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 253, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-e1b992b5617f> in <module>
     15 #     print(my_array, id(array), 'Original array')
     16 
---> 17 main(my_array)

<ipython-input-74-e1b992b5617f> in main(array)
     12   inputs = [0,1]
     13   if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 14     Parallel(n_jobs=8, verbose = 0)((foo)(array,i) for i in inputs)
     15 #     print(my_array, id(array), 'Original array')
     16 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1040 
   1041             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1042                 self.retrieve()
   1043             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1044             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    919             try:
    920                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 921                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    922                 else:
    923                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    442                     raise CancelledError()
    443                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 444                     return self.__get_result()
    445                 else:
    446                     raise TimeoutError()

/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    387         if self._exception:
    388             try:
--> 389                 raise self._exception
    390             finally:
    391                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Now, since the array has been altered, i can just wrap everything in a try, except syntax and pretend it works but i am curious as to how to actually make this error go away.
Thank you for your time
best

Comment: Show us the *full* traceback!

Comment: edited initial post so that the full traceback is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the `delayed` function in python joblib, putting the delayed in the parallel call statement executes your code without any error. e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

my_array = np.zeros((2,3))

def foo(array, x):
  for i in [0,1,2]:
    array[x][i]=25
    print(array, id(array), 'arrays in workers')

def main(array):
  print(id(array), 'Original array')
  inputs = [0, 1]
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parallel(n_jobs=8, verbose = 0, prefer='threads')([delayed(foo)(array, i) for i in inputs])
#     print(my_array, id(array), 'Original array')

main(my_array)
```

[image]

The theoretical or technical details of this function is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220458/what-does-the-delayed-function-do-when-used-with-joblib-in-python/51934579), read the accepted answer to get knowhow about the role of `delayed` in your code.

Comment: it executes without an error but it also doesnt spawn processes. I.e, my_array is full of zeros in the end

Comment: not in my machine, the output is same as without delayed but before exception

Comment: could it then be a hardware issue?
without the delayed it actually spawns the processes
with delayed it doesnt

Comment: strange i am experimenting if we can run this code without utilizing delayed

Comment: i noticed adding prefer='threads' with delayed spawns the processes